# Getting text from image on ios (image processing)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, image-processing, ocr

I am thinking of making an application that requires extracting TEXT from an image. I haven't done any thing similar and I don't want to implement the whole stuff on my own. Is there any known library or open source code (supported for ios, objective-C) which can help me in extracting the text from the image. A basic source code will also do (I will try to modify it as per my need).

Kindly let me know if some one has any idea on this.

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered today: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539649/image-processing-in-iphone>

Comment: Thanks Codo...that link helped...I am experimenting a few things with the mentioned link...will update my findings here...

Comment: @ Ross, I don't have any code as of now...I am first planning to get all the required info before starting with the coding stuff.

Comment: Check out [WeOCR](http://weocr.ocrgrid.org) project too.

Comment: Did you success in this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the main open source libraries used to do OCR on iOS is a google-sponsored open source project called [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

Here is some info on compiling tesseract for use in iOS apps:

[tesseract](http://robertcarlsen.net/2010/09/24/compiling-tesseract-v3-for-iphone-1299)

The same guy has a nice sample project on github demonstrating how a simple client might use the compiled library:

[Pocket-OCR](https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR/)

Comment: I got the code from github but it shows me a error for **baseapi.h** is not found. Help me to solve this.

Comment: same error I am also facing baseapi.h is not found, could you any solution .