# Searching an image for specified text

Tags: iphone, image-processing, ocr

I think I am going to ask very stupid Question here. In my current project i want to give search feature. I have an big image tutorial with lot of information about on a topic and i want to search feature in the image. Suppose use type like "Apple" it will show the Apple occurred how many times in the image and after clicking on of that the image scroll and go to the position where "Apple" is occurred.

Thanks for reading my stupid question but if it is possible let me know and put some sample code??

Comment: what is your problem exactly? Didn't understand. You have an image and want to search some text that is on the image. If so you would need some knowledge of OCR, text recognition and this wouldn't be as simple/stupid as you wrote above

Comment: Yes you are right sir i want to search text with in the image. I know it is not easy but if there is a way please guide me sir???

Comment: hey, please share code if you did it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a broad overview of the approach I would take:

1. Find a C/C++ based OCR library
2. Get it to compile on the iPhone
3. Create a UI to feed images to the OCR library
4. Store output of OCR, including words found and their location in the image.
5. Create a UI to allow users to enter a search.
6. Search OCR output for matches and highlight the location of matches on the image.

I imagine step 2 is going to be the most difficult. [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) may work, it is C++ based but I don't know what dependencies it has.

UPDATE: Someone on GitHub has posted a [demo iPhone App](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo) that uses Tesseract.

Comment: Yes sir i will. I am just trying to follow your guideline after success i will mark it. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to do use WebView or Core Text to render you tutorial, in which search functionality comes pretty much for free. Use OCR for search is just not practical for your need.