# iPad - taking a picture from the front camera and recognizing a driver's license

Tags: ios, ipad, camera

Is there any software or SDK out there that can take a picture of a driver's license and recognize it?  I'm thinking something like how bar code scanners work where you place the bar code infront of the camera within a specified box and it takes a picture of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any frameworks which may integrate this process, but have you considered doing it manually in few steps? Whole process may look like this:

1. Add box overlay to UIImagePicker camera view
2. Capture the picture
3. Use some OCR tool on it (for example see this: [Getting text from image on ios (image processing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538608/getting-text-from-image-on-ios-image-processing))
4. Take license number, decode it and do whatever you want