# OCR Framework that can read text from images in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, frameworks, ocr, image-recognition

I'm currently starting a project right. One of the requirements is to read details of a "Cheque"  .Meaning to say, the app should be able to read the account number, amount, etc of a certain "Cheque".

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538608/getting-text-from-image-on-ios-image-processing)
I tried something ago and works fine. Check the open source project called [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) and also a demonstration [here](https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR/) (with source code)