# How to make human verification by alphabet drawing?

Tags: ios, iphone, draw

I am currently working on new way of human verification process. In this user was able to draw two characters on already given characters.

I am manage to display two characters and allow only to touch that characters by masking view.

Now My problem was how to detect user was fully draw character properly or not.

See Below Image as per reference:

[image]

Thanks In Adv.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538608/getting-text-from-image-on-ios-image-processing

Comment: I know about tesseract but don't want to extract text from image. But I want to draw character on shown character. And after complete drawing I want to verify if user draw properly or not.

It's replacement of enter captcha code option.